# creating a single result array as response from two queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to generate a single result response from two queries that are working independently or a single query that can combine my two queries.

My first query is:

```
    $query =" SELECT *
    FROM locationdetails
    WHERE user_id = " . $userid . " AND trip IN (SELECT DISTINCT trip FROM locationdetails
    GROUP BY trip
    HAVING _id = max( _id ))
    ORDER BY trip DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5";
```

And second query is almost same:

```
$query =" SELECT *
    FROM locationdetails
    WHERE user_id = " . $userid . " AND trip IN (SELECT DISTINCT trip FROM locationdetails)
    GROUP BY trip
    HAVING _id = min( _id )
    ORDER BY trip DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5";
```

but i need to generate a single response. need some immediate help.
and also i am generating the response through a method as:

```
    function ExecuteQuery($query) {
    $response = new ApiResult();

    if (mysqli_query($this->con, $query)) {

        $results_array = array();
        $sqlResult = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);

        while ($row = $sqlResult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $results_array[] = $row;
        }

        if ($results_array != null || !empty($results_array)) {
            $response->Message = 'SUCCESSFULL';
            $response->Result = $results_array;

        } else {
            $response->Message = 'SUCCESSFULL';
            //  $response->Result = 'N;
        }
        mysqli_close($this->con);
    } else {
        $response->Message = 'Some Internal problem occurred';
        $response->Error = true;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: DISTINCT is surely redundant here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use UNION if you want unique records from both queries
AND
Use UNION ALL if you want all records from both queries.

```
    (SELECT   *
    FROM     locationdetails
    WHERE    user_id = " . $userid . " AND trip IN (SELECT DISTINCT trip FROM locationdetails
    GROUP BY trip
    HAVING   _id = max( _id ))
    ORDER BY trip DESC
    LIMIT    0 , 5
    )
    UNION
    OR
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT  *
    FROM     locationdetails
    WHERE    user_id = " . $userid . " AND trip IN (SELECT DISTINCT trip FROM locationdetails)
    GROUP BY trip
    HAVING   _id = min( _id )
    ORDER BY trip DESC
    LIMIT    0 , 5
    )
```

Comment: #thanks buddy for trying , but if you can suggest me something to create a single response using multi_query in my ExecuteQuery method.

Comment: @HarishChauhan, if the fields in both select queries are same, then < Union All > will surely help. I'm sorry I haven't used and I'm not aware of the way for Single array from multiple queries with ExecuteQuery.  However when I had a same requirement, I did it at Application side with < array_merge > or < $arr + $arr ( take care of array-keys here )> .

Comment: Don't know who in the world and why, gave a vote-down for this !

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$query =" SELECT trip, MIN(_id) AS minid, MAX(_id) AS maxid
    FROM locationdetails
    WHERE user_id = " . $userid . "
    GROUP BY trip
    ORDER BY trip DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5";
```

This will give you a list of each distinct trip, with the minimum and maximum id from each.

Comment: # Brendon rollinson: thanks your query runs well, but cannot provide me the exact result i want. i actually need all data. but if you can suggest me something on using two queries separately in my ExecuteQuery method to generate a single response.

Comment: Is the issue here that you need other fields outside of trip, MIN(_id), and MAX(_id)?

If so, do those fields stay the same for the same trip value?